# How to invoke a function of react component in redux action creator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a function shows notification in the react component for login. It need to invoke notification function after network request completed in redux action creator.

What is proper way of doing this?

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onSubmit = (values) => {
        this.props.SignIn(values)
    }

    showNotification(notificationType, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, notificationPosition, notificationContent) {
    this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
            title: notificationTitle,
            message: notificationMessage,...
        });
    }

    render() {
    //it works fine here.. 
    //this.showNotification('danger', 'Danger', 'Document has been permanently removed', 'top-right')
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
                <div className="login-cover">
                    <div className="login-cover-image" style={{ backgroundImage: 'url("/assets/img/login-bg/login-bg-14.jpg")'}}></div>
                    <div className="login-cover-bg"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="login login-v2">
                    <div className="login-content">
                        <form className="margin-bottom-0" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                            <div className="login-buttons">             
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Sign me in</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="m-t-20">
                                Not a member yet? Click <Link to="/kayitol">here</Link> to register.
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    const {Auth} = state;
    return {
        Auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {SignIn})(Login);
```

SignInAction.js:

```
export const SignIn= ({username, password}) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:44325/api/auth/authenticate', {username, password});
        ...

    } catch (error) {
        //instead of alert, how to call showNotification here ?
        alert("Login Failed!")

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to dispatch the action: https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add callback functions to `SignIn`. Something like:

```
 this.props.SignIn(values, {successCallback: fn, failureCallback: fn})
```

and modify the `SignIn`

```
export const SignIn= ({username, password}, {successCallback, failureCallback}) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:44325/api/auth/authenticate', {username, password});

      if(typeof successCallback === 'function'){
        successCallback();
      }

    } catch (error) {
        alert("Login Failed!")

      if(typeof failureCallback === 'function'){
        failureCallback();
      }
    }
}
```

or return the axios request from the action creator and then just do

```
this.props.SignIn(values).then(()=>....).catch(()=>...);
```